# Multiple scanf from a single input

Tags: c

I am trying to prompt the user for a number, and then extract the number they entered and also sum the digits of the number they entered.  They can only enter the number once.  My code is below:

```
    printf("\nPART 2: EXPRESSIONS SUM\n\n");
    printf("Enter 5-digit integer: ");
    scanf("\n%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &dig_one, &dig_two, &dig_three, &dig_four, &dig_five);
    scanf("\n%d", &five_dig_int)
```

However after the first scanf completes, the program gets hung on the second scanf waiting for more input.  Is there a way to "re scan" so to speak on the initial input so the user does not have to enter the number again?  Thanks!
;

Comment: You can read the user's input as a whole line, as a string, using `fgets` or maybe `scanf`, then use `sscanf` multiple times to scan that string various ways.

Comment: Interesting, I will give that a try.  So it looks like there is not a way to do it using only scanf correct?  Since after using it once the input is "eaten up" so to speak.

Comment: Alternatively, could I keep the scanf that gets the digits, then concatenate them together into a string and convert it to the full 5 digit int? How would I do that if I wanted to go that route?

Comment: `scanf(" %c%c%c%c%c", &str[0], &str[1], &str[2], &str[3], &str[4])`

Comment: @Froobyflake Yes, the fact that the input, once scanned, is "eaten up" is what makes `scanf` and `fscanf` very, very difficult to use for any kind of sophisticated, flexible, or error-tolerant parsing.  That's why I always recommend reading whole lines into a buffer (using `fscanf` or the equivalent), then doing whatever it takes to parse the line.  That way you can do anything you want with the buffer: you can back up and try parsing it several different ways, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string & atoi()

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[6];
    printf("\nPART 2: EXPRESSIONS SUM\n\n");
    printf("Enter 5-digit integer: ");
    scanf("\n%s, &str);
    int fivedigit = atoi(str);
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int tempadd = (int) str[i];
        sum += tempadd;
    }
    //Do stuff with both values



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to sum the base 10 digits of any integer with a bit of arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int val;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  if (scanf("%d", &val) != 1) return 1;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int x = val; x; x /= 10) sum += x % 10;
  printf("Value = %d. Digit sum = %d\n", val, sum);
  return 0;
}
```